# Unable to create Branch when branch name contains $variable

Tags: git

I am unable to create branch locally, When passing variable in branch name, I am unable to create the branch.

```
cd project-directory
export VERSION="`grep VERSION version.txt | cut -d"=" -f2`"
echo $VERSION
response:
**20.12.20**


git checkout -b test-release/${VERSION}
response:
**fatal: '20.12.20' is not a commit and a branch 'test-release/' cannot be created from it**

git checkout -b test-release/20.12.20
response
**Switched to a new branch 'test-release/20.12.20'**
```

May I know what could be the wrong

Comment: If you look well, your `$VERSION` variable has a multi-line value: `response:\n**20.12.20**` that might be confusing GIT.

Comment: There are spaces in `VERSION` so `git checkout -b test-release/${VERSION}` is expanded to `git checkout -b test-release/ 20.12.20`. Strip the spaces from `VERSION`.

Comment: Thank you variable has leading white space, after trimming the it i am able to create branch. Thank you. phd and aledpardo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where else they're documented, but [`git check-ref-format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) checks refnames against all the rules:

> Git imposes the following rules on how references are named:
>
> 1. They can include slash / for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no slash-separated component can begin with a dot . or end with the sequence .lock.
> 2. They must contain at least one /. This enforces the presence of a category like heads/, tags/ etc. but the actual names are not restricted. If the --allow-onelevel option is used, this rule is waived.
> 3. They cannot have two consecutive dots .. anywhere.
> 4. They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values are lower than \040, or \177 DEL), space, tilde ~, caret ^, or colon : anywhere.
> 5. They cannot have question-mark ?, asterisk *, or open bracket [ anywhere. See the --refspec-pattern option below for an exception to this rule.
> 6. They cannot begin or end with a slash / or contain multiple consecutive slashes (see the --normalize option below for an exception to this rule)
> 7. They cannot end with a dot ..
> 8. They cannot contain a sequence @{.
> 9. They cannot be the single character @.
> 10. They cannot contain a \.

note that the full spell of a branch name is `refs/heads/` that branch name.